# Qt: How to add/delete rows to a TableView populated with SQL records?

Tags: sql-server, qt, uitableview, insert, delete-row

I am using Qt5 and MS-SQL Server 2014 on Windows7.
In my app I need to be able to perform some changes in a database table.

*The DB table looks like this*:
[image]

*Code*:

```
DepotTable::DepotTable(QWidget * parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DepotTable)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    model = new QSqlTableModel(this);
    model->setTable("DEPOTS");
    model->select();
    model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);

    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    ui->tableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::SelectedClicked);
}
```

I created the table(view) using `QTableView` and `QSqlTableModel`, just to be able to fetch all rows from the database table. I can also change/modify the values of any cell/column.
And, when changes are done, I can commit/submit all changes back to database table, when pressing *Ok* button: `model->submitAll()`;.

Yet, I still have one problem: I don't know how to insert a new row and edit its related values. Also, how to delete a certain/selected row? (Ok, it seems in fact there are two problems: `1) insert&edit` and `2) delete row`)